# PHP Returns an Object and a Array when declaration is similar

Tags: php, arrays, output

I have a issue with the return of my multidimensional arrays. For some reason two of them are returned as objects and not arrays when the initialization is fairly the same.

I'm creating a time card and would like to return the % of time an employee was late and on time in a month for the total of past 12 months.

Code:

```
$eID = $_GET['showLatencyValues'];

//get the last 12 months
$month = time();
for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) {
  $month = strtotime( date( 'Y-m-01' )." -$i months");
  $months[] = date("r", $month);
}


$ii = 0;    
for($i = 11; $i >= 0; $i--) {
    $m = explode(" ", $months[$i]);
    $result = $m[2].'. '.$m[3];
    $last12months[$ii][0] = $ii;
    $last12months[$ii][1] = $result;
    $ii++;
}

//set the correct dates
$f = explode(" ", $last12months[0][1]);
$t = explode(" ", $last12months[11][1]);

$from   = $f[1].'-'.letterToNumeric($f[0]).'-01';
$days   = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, letterToNumeric($t[0]), $t[1]); // 31
$to     = $t[1].'-'.letterToNumeric($t[0]).'-'.$days;

//get the information from database
$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT DISTINCT `timeIn`,`date` FROM `clock` WHERE `eID`='$eID' AND date BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to'");
$res = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
$break = explode("-", $res['date']);
$month = $break[1]; //set current month to
$countMonth = 0; //month number
$count = 0; //day number
$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT min(timeIn) as timeIn,`date` FROM `clock` WHERE `eID`='$eID' AND date BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to' group by date");
while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $break = explode("-", $res['date']); //get the current selected month
    if($month != $break[1]) {           //check if current month is the same as selected by database if not then
        $countMonth++; //add current month number
        $count = 0;    //set current day number to 0
        $month = $break[1]; //set the current month to whatever is selected by database
    }
    $timeInData[$countMonth][$count] = $res['timeIn'];
    $count++;
}

$count = 0;
for($i = 0; $i < count($timeInData); $i++) {
    for($s = 0; $s < count($timeInData[$i]); $s++) {
        $firstShift_timeIn = setting($conn, 'timeIn1');
        $secondShift_timeIn = setting($conn, 'timeIn2');
        $lateConsideredAfter = setting($conn, 'lateAfter');

        $actualTime = date("H:i", strtotime($timeInData[$i][$s]));
        if($res_shift['shift'] == 1)    $considerLateTime = date("H:i", strtotime($firstShift_timeIn." +".$lateConsideredAfter." minutes"));
        else                            $considerLateTime = date("H:i", strtotime($secondShift_timeIn." +".$lateConsideredAfter." minutes"));

        if($actualTime > $considerLateTime) $late[$count]++;
        else $onTime[$count]++;                 
    }
    $count++;
}

if($count != 12) {
    $amt = (12-($count))-1;
    for($w = 0; $w <= $amt; $w++) {
        $onTimeYesData[$w][0] = $w;
        $onTimeYesData[$w][1] = 0;
        $onTimeNoData[$w][0] = $w;
        $onTimeNoData[$w][1] = 0;
    }
}

for($q = ($amt+1); $q <= 11; $q++) {
    $total = $onTime[($q-($amt+1))] + $late[($q-($amt+1))];

    $onTimeYesData[$q][0] = $q;

    $onTimeYesData[$q][1] = round(($onTime[($q-($amt+1))]/$total)*100);

    $onTimeNoData[$q][0] = $q;

    $onTimeNoData[$q][1] = round(($late[($q-($amt+1))]/$total)*100);
}

$response[1] = $last12months;
$response[0] = $onTimeYesData;
$response[2] = $onTimeNoData;

echo json_encode($response[1])."\n\n".json_encode($response[0])."\n\n".json_encode($response[2]);
```

Output that I receive:

> [[0,"Mar. 2019"],[1,"Apr. 2019"],[2,"May. 2019"],[3,"Jun.
>   2019"],[4,"Jul. 2019"],[5,"Aug. 2019"],[6,"Sep. 2019"],[7,"Oct.
>   2019"],[8,"Nov. 2019"],[9,"Dec. 2019"],[10,"Jan. 2020"],[11,"Feb.
>   2020"]]
>
> {"1":[1,90],"2":[2,100],"3":[3,96],"4":[4,91],"5":[5,95],"6":[6,95],"7":[7,100],"8":[8,92],"9":[9,95],"10":[10,89],"11":[11,88]}
>
> {"1":[1,10],"2":[2,0],"3":[3,4],"4":[4,9],"5":[5,5],"6":[6,5],"7":[7,0],"8":[8,8],"9":[9,5],"10":[10,11],"11":[11,13]}

I expect the two other outputs to be in the same format as the first one.

Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If your arrays don't have a value for each numerical index starting from 0, then it will considered as a hash (or "object", JS-wise) when JSON-encoding it. In your case, they seem to be missing a value for the 0 index.

Comment: Hint: in JS and JSON, array indexes start at 0.

Comment: Or, you can go the easy way: replace `json_encode($yourThing)` with `json_encode(array_values($yourThing))`. Not exactly pretty, though.

Comment: Agreed with comments above. On a separate note, not seeing where `$amt` is defined outside of the condition on `!=12`.